# android eclipse custom version of same project

Tags: android, manifest

I want to try 2 difference version of the same app on my tablet.

So imported both project in eclipse with different project name.

I changed the name of the app in the manifest, I changed the icon to be able to recognize them on my desktop ...

I just can't get both on the phone at the same time. I can execute them both, but installing one is gonna erase the other.

I guess its the change I'm looking for is in the manifest.xml, still I can't find it.

Comment: change the package name,

Comment: Change the package name,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your package name. A Package name must be unique for every app.

From the [official doc](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html)

> **Package Name** is the package namespace for your app (following the same
>   rules as packages in the Java programming language). Your package name
>   must be unique across all packages installed on the Android system.
>   For this reason, it's generally best if you use a name that begins
>   with the reverse domain name of your organization or publisher entity.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, in the Package Explorer select the com.xxxx.yyyy in the src/ directory of the project whose manifest you changed. Right click -> Refactor -> Rename. Enter a new package name, e.g. com.abc.test

Then, in the manifest XML, also replace all instances of "com.xxxx.yyyy" with the new "com.abc.test" package name.